# Cannot create a string with "@" symbol inside the text in Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

I'm trying to create a simple string like:

`test = "abc@email.com"` in Pydev but it automatically interpret `"@"` as a special symbol and the statement cannot pe done.
When I focus on the variable in Pydev, I can see:
  test = "abc**@email.com"** instead of `test = "abc@email.com"`

Anyone has any idea why I have this issue?

If I run the statement in windows command prompt python, then it is correctly assigned.

Does it have any relation with pylint?

Thanks,

Comment: Most likely you forgot to close a string literal on a preceding line.

Comment: Possibly pylint - I just did a quick test in the middle of one of the modules I'm working on, and `test = "abc@abc.com"` works fine for me sans a pep8 error (variable not used)

Comment: I checked the syntax and seems to be ok. I put another string like a_str = "abcd" before test = "abc@email.com" and it is ok.

Comment: How does it automatically interpret "@" as a special symbol? A common way to get around such problems it to prefix "special" characters with something to indicate they are to be taken literally. See if there's something about that in PyDev's documentation.

Comment: You can mark a string as raw by preceding it with an `r`. For instance, `test = r"abc@email.com"`.

Comment: it still doesn't work with test = r"abc@email.com"

Comment: Try opening the file with a simple text editor to see exactly what's inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce similar result was with unclosed string before that, which is obviously a syntax error. Otherwise I've never seen any problems with string literals  containing `@` while using PyDev (with PyLint).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try `%@`?

this might be your answer. Not a whole lot out there about special characters in python.

Comment: This answer seems to me as a mere guessing. What special meaning is `%` supposed to have, especially in this context?

Comment: I saw it being used to place other special characters, and it was a guess. It was the best I could come up with, there doesn't seem to be any reference to '@' in the docs on strings at all